# await doesn't wait for the function to end

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm new to javascript and I tried to implement my first async await and can't figure out where is my problem.

getName() - should return a promise after 1s.
f() - should wait for getName to finish and then print name

What am I missing ?

```
const getName = async () => {
  setTimeout(() => 'xxx', 1000)
};

const f = async () => {
  name = await getName()
  console.log(name)
}

f()
```

Comment: The `async` keyword does two things: 1) Makes it possible to use `await` inside the function (which you don't do in `getName`). 2) Makes the function return a Promise no matter what.

Comment: It doesn't change behaviour in any way, and since your function without `getName` would just return `undefined`, the async keyword effectively just makes it return `Promise.resolve( undefined )` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you're using `await` also inside `getName`, you don't need to have `getName` async, you just need to return a `Promise`; since `await` works with promises:

```
const getName = () => 
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'xxx'));

async f() {
  let name = await getName();
  console.log(name);
}

f();
```

Comment: The difference is that `async` wraps the `returned` value in a fulfilled promise: "return value of an async function is implicitly wrapped in `Promise.resolve`"  (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Therefore you don't have the granularity needed to resolve when something happens (e.g. waiting one second), it will be resolved immediately. Basically those are equivalent: `const a = async  ()  => true` and `const b = () => Promise.resolve(true)`.

Comment: sorry for deleting my question which you answered in this comment ^. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

To await a function, that function must return a promise.

You thus need to create a new promise. It will have 2 methods: `resolve`, and `reject`.

1. `resolve` returns the variable, and is used on success. You can catch its return value by using `promise.then(value => )` or by `await`ing it.
2. `reject` throws an error, and is used on error. You can catch the error by using `promise.catch(err => )` or by awaiting the async function and wrapping it in a try-catch block.

Here is how your code should look:

```js
const getName = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('xxx');
    }, 1000)
  })
};

const f = async () => {
  name = await getName()
  console.log(name)
}

f()
```

Comment: His function was async, so it already returned a Promise, although it was a Promise was immediately resolved with the value `undefined`.

Comment: You're right, ran some more tests in console and figured that out. Deleted comment instead of editing it and sadly can't bring it back up any more. Edit: this is getting out of hands.